# Absence of some repositories in the root resource

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I'm learning source code of the [Restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks). I can't find out why a response from the root resource hasn't got relations of *org.springsource.restbucks.payment.PaymentRepository* and *org.springsource.restbucks.payment.CreditCardRepository*.

```
    {
      "_links": {
        "restbucks:orders": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders{?page,size,sort,projection}",
          "templated": true
        },
        "restbucks:engine": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/engine"
        },
        "restbucks:pages": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/pages"
        },
        "curies": [
          {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/rels/{rel}",
            "name": "restbucks",
            "templated": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Could you explain to me how it works?

Thanks

Comment: Root listing only list top level resources. Payments is a sub resource under `/orders`

Comment: Can you point out in source code where it happens?